# Find the number of sets satisfying the conditions

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, contest-math

> Let $ N$ be the number of ordered pairs of nonempty sets $ \mathcal{A}$ and $ \mathcal{B}$ that have the following properties:
>
> • $ \mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{B} = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$,
>
> • $ \mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \emptyset$,
>
> • The number of elements of $ \mathcal{A}$ is not an element of $ \mathcal{A}$,
>
> • The number of elements of $ \mathcal{B}$ is not an element of $ \mathcal{B}$.
>
> Find $ N$

If $A$ has $k$ elements out of the $12$ elements there are (only with the $|A| \notin A$ constraint) $\binom{12 - 1}{k} = \binom{11}{k}$. Since one of them is $|A|$.

It is a similar process in choosing sets for $B$ except $B$ cannot have any elements that $A$ has.

But taking a bit backwards. There are a total of:

$\sum_{k=1}^{11} \binom{11}{k} = 2047$ This is automatically wrong since $N < 1000$ is a bound.

**Hints only please.**

### **EDIT:**

I misunderstood the question, so here is an update.

Since $A \cup B = \{1 \to 12\}$ I understand that $|A| \in B$ and $|B| \in A$.

Also $|A| \ne 6, |B| \ne 6$.

So take casework:

$|A| = 1, |B| = 11 \implies \binom{10}{0} = 1$ set.

$|A| = 2, |B| = 10$. Now: $|B| \in A, |A| \in B$ hence, $\binom{10}{1} \cdot \binom{9}{9} = 10$

$|A| = 3, |B| = 9$. Now: $\binom{10}{2} \cdot \binom{8}{8} = 45$

Likewise for the rest except $|A| = 6$ we have:

$|A| = 4, |B| = 8$. Now: $\binom{10}{3} \cdot \binom{7}{7} = 120$

We have then:

$1 + \binom{10}{1} + \binom{10}{2} + \binom{10}{3} + \binom{10}{4}+\binom{10}{6}+\cdots+ \binom{10}{10}$

$$=\sum_{r=0}^{10} \binom{10}{r} - \binom{10}{5} = 772$$

Comment: You're certainly overcounting. For example, when $|\mathcal{A}|=1$, you must have $1 \not \in \mathcal{A}$ and $11 \not \in \mathcal{B}$. This forces $\mathcal{A}=\{11\}$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{ 1, 2, \dots, 10, 12 \}$. If I were you I'd use the fact that we must have $|\mathcal{A}| \in \mathcal{B}$ and $|\mathcal{B}| \in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Why must we have $|A| \in B$ and $|B| \in A$ though? Take: $A = \{1, 3\}$ and $B = \{4, 5\}$? @CliveNewstead

Comment: Because of the first condition you list;
$$\{ 1, 3 \} \cup \{ 4, 5 \} \ne \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 \}$$

Comment: You might want to read @CliveNewstead's first comment again.

Comment: @user84413, yeah I did read it. I got the right answer, one small typo, which I am fixing now

Comment: Thanks for making that change; I made a small edit also, but feel free to change it if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

If $|A| = 6$, then $|B| = 12 - |A| = 12 - 6 = 6$, and as one of $A$ and $B$ must contain $6$, this cannot happen.

If $|A| = k \ne 6$, what numbers are forced to be in a specific set, and what numbers are free to be in either set? Can you get the number of pairs where $|A| = k$ this way?

Once you've done the above, what are all the possibilities $k$ that let $|A| = k$? How many total pairs does this give you?